# UITableView in xcode playground is not showing text/subtitles

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, wwdc

I was following an article about WWDC17. Everything was fine, but my live view is not looking like what it should be. The (.subtitle) and table cell are not showing anything

Could anyone please help me how I could do this work?

Following is the playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class WWDCMasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var reasons = ["WWDC is great", "the people are awesome", "I love lab works", "key of success"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = "Reason I should attend WWDC18"
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle , reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        }

        let reason = reasons[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "I want to attend because\(reason)"
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Reason #\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
    }
}

let master = WWDCMasterViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: master)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are missing `UITableViewDataSource`'s method `numberOfRowsInSection`, so your UITableView is ended up having 0 rows, try adding following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.reasons.count
}
```

Here is the fixed Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class WWDCMasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var reasons = ["WWDC is great", "the people are awesome", "I love lab works", "key of success"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = "Reason I should attend WWDC18"
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.reasons.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle , reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        }

        let reason = reasons[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "I want to attend because\(reason)"
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Reason #\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
    }
}

let master = WWDCMasterViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: master)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nav
```